# create hyperlink to database record in servlet

Tags: mysql, html, servlets

I have a databse table called article with three fields(Id, Title, Text). I am using servlet. I have got a query to select the id and titles from the table. What I'd like to do is showing the list of the titles as hyperlinks and linking each of the titles to their texts from the databse table
this is my code

```
String SQL_QUERY ="Select article.title , article.articleId from article where        article.title like '% "+searchWord+"%'";
          Query query = session.createSQLQuery(SQL_QUERY);
          List result = query.list();     
         for(Iterator it=result.iterator();it.hasNext();){  
              Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
             String title = ((String) row[0]);
             int id = ((Integer) row[1]);
             out.println("<a Link to the text> title </a>")
          }
```

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: your search clause has `'% ' searchword` there. (extra space character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a hyper link which in turn calls Servlet with it.

e.g.

```
out.println("<a href=\""+request.getContextPath()+"/articleServlet?id="+id+"\">"+title+"</a>");
```

This will call `doGet()` method of associated `Servlet`. Then rest is the known story.

Comment: What do I need to write in the body of the doGet() method ?

Comment: request.getParameter("id") which will return clicked record's id.